# Write a C program that reads in the integers from the accompanying data file and use insertion sort to store the sorted data into an array

Tags: c, arrays, selection-sort

> Write a C program that implements a simple array-based insertion sort.
>   Your program must read in the integers from the accompanying data file
>   and use insertion sort to store the sorted data into an array. If you
>   must insert an element between two existing values, then you must also
>   move (or shift) the elements all elements with an index >= the index
>   where you wish to insert the new element. Note that you can find the
>   insertion sort algorithm in the textbook and the slides.

This is the ints from the text file. The ints are under each other and not the way they are shown here:
879
646
80
385
741
57
370
240
111
400
262
678
951
506
720
508
792
863
677
864
70
5
591
440
989
478
867
636
278
827
692
243
806
676
158
550
425
226
783
129
876
714
125
721
164
555
730
146
596
947
174
837
48
589
808
868
694
677
379
62
580
165
956
139
215
14
45
552
98
154
702
661
997
825
363
782
229
915
281
397
295
219
231
476
253
22
873
504
653
698
772
184
453
508
977
863
624
947
104
926

This the code I have for now. I am getting the addresses in order but now the integers from the file. When i comment out the insertionSort function, the numbers print fine but obviously not in order. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void insertionSort(int *, int);

int main()
{
    int i,num,array[1000];

    FILE *fp = fopen("data_a5.txt","r");

    fscanf(fp,"%d",&num); 

    if(fp== NULL)
    {
        printf("Error reading File!\n");
        return;
    }  

    while(!feof(fp))
    { 
        fscanf(fp,"%d", &array[num]);
        //printf("%d\n", array[num]);
    }

    insertionSort(array,num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        printf("%d\n",&array[i]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

void insertionSort(int *value, int size)
{
    int i,j,temp;

    for(i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        for(j = i; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if(value[j+1]<value[j])
            {
                temp=value[j+1];
                value[j+1]=value[j];
                value[j]=temp;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. This is unreadable.

Comment: [while(!feof(fp)) is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/3386109) and lots of other problems. It would help if you removed all of the blank lines and indented the code properly, so that people can read it.

Comment: 1. You should not use `feof` to check end of file. 2. `fscanf(fp,"%d", &array[num]);` you are writing all data to the same array cell

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Then [edit] your question so there is `input`, `expected output` and a what you have done already - the last thing is actually ok.

Answer (score -1):

If your task is to have your array sorted as items are inserted (ie. "live") you best bet is to use linked structures.

For example:

```
struct myinst
{
  int mynum;
  struct myinst *prev;
  struct myinst *next;
};
```

There a lot of examples, here is one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_program_in_c.htm

When you insert a new item to have your array/linked list sorted you go through your linked list and find the item that is nearest to the new one and then perform an insert by creating new memory an change prev/next addresses in existing items so that they point to the new item.

Comment: It sounds more like a comment than an answer